# facebook comments - synching comments from blog -> fb company page/wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-fql

**Overview:**
I use the fb:comments plugin on my website - in this case Facebook will use the full URL of the page as the ID for which comments will be related to / stored on facebook.

Like many other sites we also have a company facebook page on which we post a "link" to an article. As we know, Facebook automatically parses the link, pulls in the post image and a blurb. Furthermore, Facebook users leave comments on this "link" posted on our wall.

**My question is:**
Is it possible to synch comments left on my company wall post WITH comments left through the plugin on my site - they both share the same "link" - e.g. on the Facebook wall we enter the link url which corresponds to the same page of my website where the Facebook comments plugin is pulling comments using that same "link"

**Another way of looking at it**
We post a new link to our Facebook company page and within 1 hour we get 30 comments on the link "http://www.mysite.com/2011/my-post/"

Our actual website post at "http://www.mysite.com/2011/my-post/" has the Facebook comments plugin on the page pointing href="http://www.mysite.com/2011/my-post/" but here it only shows 3 comments that were left by facebook users on our site

Is it possible that on our site at "http://www.mysite.com/2011/my-post/" it would show the same comments that it would show on our Facebook company page for the same link?

Thanks in advance for any feedback :)

Comment: It should work, but it's hard to diagnose without any example of the code you're using or the sites where this is located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in elegant way. Facebook treat comments under link on your FB page and comments on your website as comments to different object.

In FB model of the world comments on your website are about your article, and comments on your wall are about fact that your posted link to your article.

In my personal experience (i have site with same problem as you) comments on website are better quality than comments on FB page. So in fact it's better for you and your readers that you don't display those comments on web page.

BTW. there are two trick if you must show comments from FB page on website (it will not work in other direction), but I not recommend any of those:

1. Login on Facebook as your page and post comment below your article. Your comment will be showed on your wall and comments from this post will be displayed on your website too.
2. Fetch comments from your FB page using Open Graph and display them on website as normal HTML.